# Visualization of Affine Space and Projective Space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

i have been self studying algebraic geometry and have always struggled to grasp how affine spaces naturally "lie" in projective Space, as in, i haven't found any convincing sketches of what that would look like in even the simplest of cases; $\mathbb{A}^1$ and $\mathbb{P}^1$. I do understand the concept of "points at infinity" and that parallel lines intersect in projective space, but this isn't enough for me to say "yeah i could totally explain this to someone else".

This is how i would visualize it right now : When i hear of Projective space $\mathbb{P}^1$ all i think about is a bunch of lines passing through the origin in 2-dimensional space. (Probably as wrong as it gets)

Does anyone have some nice literature that focuses on explaining these things in a very visual manner?

Comment: Maybe of interest? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452958/understanding-projective-plane-conceptually-page-342-road-to-reality-by-roger and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447567/flag-manifold-to-complex-projective-line

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand\L{\mathbb{L}}\newcommand\P{\mathbb{P}}\newcommand\A{\mathbb{A}}\newcommand\C{\mathbb{C}}$ Since you're trying to learn algebraic geometry, I'll assume that we're talking about complex projective spaces.

$\P^1$ does indeed consist of all lines in $\C^2$ passing through the origin. Any line that does NOT pass through the origin is an affine line. If we denote such a line by $\A^1$, then there is a natural map
\begin{align*}\A^1 &\rightarrow \P^1\\
p &\mapsto \ell,
\end{align*}
where $\ell$ is the line through the origin that intersects $\A^1$ at $p$. There is only one line through the origin that does not intersect $\A^1$, namely the line parallel to $\A^1$. That point in $\P^1$ is called the "point at infinity".

Recall that homogeneous coordinates is a map
\begin{align*}
\pi: \C^2\backslash\{0\} &\rightarrow \P^1\\
(z^1,z^2) &\mapsto [z^1,z^2],
\end{align*}
$[z^1,z^2] \subset \C^2$ is the line that contains $(0,0)$ and $(z^1,z^2)$.
Now let $$\A^1 = \{ (1,z)\ :\ z \in \C\}\text{ and }\L^1 = \{ (0,z)\ : z\in\C\} $$
There are bijective maps
\begin{align*}
\C &\rightarrow \A^1 \stackrel{\pi}{\rightarrow} \P\backslash\L\\
z &\mapsto (1,z) \mapsto [1,z].
\end{align*}
This defines affine coordinates on $\P\backslash\L$. More generally, given any affine line $\A^1 \subset \C^2$, there is an affine parameterization $$a: \C \rightarrow \A^1$$ and affine coordinates with respect to this affine line is the bijective map
\begin{align*}
\C &\stackrel{a}{\rightarrow} \A^1 \stackrel{\pi}{\rightarrow} \P^1\backslash\L,
\end{align*}

All of this generalizes to higher dimensions in a straightforward way.

Comment: Very insightful, thanks a lot!